# How do I generate (and label) a random integer with python 3.2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, integer, label

Okay, so I'm admittedly a newbie to programming, but I can't determine how to get python v3.2 to generate a random positive integer between parameters I've given it. Just so you can understand the context, I'm trying to create a guessing-game where the user inputs parameters (say 1 to 50), and the computer generates a random number between the given numbers. The user would then have to guess the value that the computer has chosen. I've searched long and hard, but all of the solutions I can find only tell one how to get earlier versions of python to generate a random integer. As near as I can tell, v.3.2 changed how to generate and label a random integer. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Nope, nothing changed in this regard in Python 3.

Answer (score 11):

Use [random.randrange](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/random.html#random.randrange) or [random.randint](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/random.html#random.randint) (Note the links are to the Python 3k docs).

```
In [67]: import random
In [69]: random.randrange(1,10)
Out[69]: 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random` module:

```
import random

# Random integer >= 5 and < 10
random.randrange(5, 10)
```