# Python and random.randint()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following problem from school: the teacher has asked us to divide to sides with 2/3 and 1/3 probabilities using the `randint` function.

I really don't understand how this `randint` function on probabilities works.

```
import random

rand = (random.randint(1,100))
        if rand >= 67  :
                print ("obj A 1/3")
        else:
                print ("obj B 2/3")
```

This does not work.

Comment: *"really don't understand how this works... does not work"* - what?! Please read [ask], and try to find someone who can help you translate better to English.

Comment: Remember that indentation is **essential** in Pythong, so take care of it.

Comment: What don't you understand? Do you understand what `random.randint()` is doing? Do you understand what variable assignment is doing? Do you understand conditionals?

Comment: Yes I understand all that. What I don't understand is, how to use randint to differentiate between 1/3 and 2/3.

Comment: Seems like that's more of a maths issue than a programming issue - 2/3 is (roughly) 67/100

Answer (score 3):

One key skill you must learn is using documentation. A quick search brought me to the Python manual page on [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint):

> Return a random integer *N* such that `a <= N <= b`.

Your creating a variable `rand` which is equal to a random number `>= 1` and `<= 100`. The next line is a conditional that checks if your number is `>= 67`...this will only be true ~1/3 of the time.

---

Side note: there's no benefit to using a random number between 1-100. Your code would be much more straightforward (and therefore Pythonic) if you looked for exactly what you wanted (i.e. 1/3).

```
import random

rand = random.randint(1, 3)
if rand is 1:
    print '1/3'
else:
    print '2/3'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
random.randint(1,100)
```

This returns a number from 1 to 100. So, 1/3 is about 33 and 2/3 is about 66. So the first `if` statement is seeing that if the number is equal or greater than than 67, print `"obj A 1/3"`, which is this part:

```
if rand >= 67:
    print ("obj A 1/3")
```

Anything else, then print `"obj A 2/3"`, which is the last part:

```
else:
    print ("obj B 2/3")
```

Of course, you need to use `print()` like that and not like this, `print ()` unless you want a Syntax error. Also, the math is wrong. The program should look more like this:

```
import random
rand = (random.randint(1, 3))
if rand == 1:
    print("obj C 3/3")
elif rand == 2:
    print("obj A 2/3")
elif rand == 1:
    print("obj B 1/3")
```

The above math is the most accurate as you have a 1/3 chance of getting one of the numbers, which corresponds to the numerator in the fraction, x over 3, where `rand` is equal to x.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're trying to do but you need to start here by reading up on [random](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/random.html). Check out this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522733/how-do-i-generate-and-label-a-random-integer-with-python-3-2), I think it will explain things better.  Your current code will get a syntax error, I think what you're looking to do is this:

```
import random

rand = (random.randint(1,100))
if rand >= 67:
    print("1/3rd")  # Do the 1/3rd things...
else:
    print("2/3rd")  # Do the 2/rd things...
```

I implore you to go read up on python though. PS. A more accurate solution would be to generate a random int from 1 to 3 instead of thinking of the problem in terms of 1-100.  Then your probability becomes more accurate since 1/3rd = 33.3333... of the time, its hard to represent it using 1-100.

Comment: sry, yeah I forgot the import random part. Still.... my teachers says the code is wrong and it does not give 1/3 or 2/3 answers. Logically taken my code does that.

Comment: Yeah because your code is generating random int from 1 to 100, and the split is at >= 67. You need to simplify the problem and use `random.randint(1,3)` and then `if rand <= 1` and `else` condition will give you the other 2/3rds.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?  Simplify to the level of your denominator: 3.  Generate one of three integers, with equal probability.  You'll get 1, 2, and 3; each appears 1/3 of the time.

```
rand = random.randint(1,3)
    if rand == 1:
        print ("obj A 1/3")
    else:
        print ("obj B 2/3")
```

Is this simple enough for you to understand?  In your original code, you were generating 100 different integers.  You did the "A" part in 34 of those cases.  That's 34%, a little more than the requested 1/3.